# What is better approach for using a foreign key member in a class? Composition of the whole object or just declaring a variable

Tags: c#, oop

Lets suppose I have a class Student and a class ExamRecord. Now ExamRecord uses Student.ID as foreign key in the DB. How should I cater it in the Front-end model? Should I use composition and make an object of type Student as member of ExamRecord (so I can use its ID later on when needed to be) or just declare a simple int (assume int is the datatype of the ID) and use it for storing Student ID in the ExamRecord?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with storing it as an int in the class. I'll try to explain why.

When working with databases you're trying to model relationships between entities, like in your case you have an `ExamRecord` which has a foreign key to a `Student`. Now this might seem like it could be (and surely it can) be translated directly to program code. But there's a semantic difference here that I think is fairly important.

That is, as mentioned, when working with relational databases you model `relationships` and in your code you're trying to model `objects` with the help of `classes`. These `objects` do have different relationships with other objects, otherwise it would be very hard to code and in OOP the relationships is one of its strengths.
However you've surely heard about `Is a` (inheritance/interfaces) and `Has a`(composition) which is the common way of talking about OOP-relationships. Does the exam record **have a student**?

I guess what I'm trying to say with my ramblings above is that the models in a database are different from the models in a program.

What it boils down to is semantics, what makes sense and what conveys the meaning of your code the best? I said that I'd go with the ExamRecord storing the student-id because to me it sounds strange that an **ExamRecord** `has a` **Student**, the other way around though makes perfect sense. But again, it's about what makes sense in the context of your program and only you can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

- It is the reference to Student object that becomes part of ExamRecord
  and not the copy.
- Having id and performing lookups is not a good approach.
- Most of the Object Relational Mappers (ORM) like entity framework, Nhibernate follow this approach

Ofcourse, when you are storing this in the database you need to store the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Daniel Figueroa, that just using an ID sounds fine if you need to refer to a student from an exam.

I'd like to challenge the premise here though; in the database, you might have to refer to a `student` from an `exam`, but in your OO code however, it might be more natural to turn this around: Are you sure you don't just want each `student` to keep it's own internal list of `exam` objects?

It might be that you absolutely need to be able to look up a student via an `exam`, and that your are therefor forced to choose between the two options in your original question. If not however, then perhaps an exam does not even need to "know" about which student it belongs to.

I'm not saying you should remove the `StudentId` entirely from your `exam`-object - just that you should think carefully about the relationship between these, and which of then you should access through the other.

Put a little different: I'm assuming a `student` can have several exams, and somehow it feels a little "messy" to me that several exams should refer to the same student. I would prefer that anything to be done with an exam, should be done through the student that "owns" that exam, if possible.